# Getting lockups/hangs when using jsTestDriver with Intellij idea 9 (doesn't work at all on 10)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intellij-idea, freeze, js-test-driver

Is anyone using jsTestDriver with IntelliJ? What version are you using? Is it working well?

I am using IntelliJ right off the website 9.0.4 with jsTestRunner 1.2.2 and I repeatedly get hangs when I run all tests.

I decided to run the server in a terminal rather than within IDEA, but it still hangs.

If I run the server and the tests in 2 terminal windows, I get 100% working functionality, even when I use Opera, Firefox and Chrome at the same time. All 15 tests pass (45 tests total).

So is the plugin broken with Idea? Can anyone help me get this working with idea? It used to work just fine when I had 4 or 6 tests... but now that I give it anything remotely complex, it bombs.

Please help. I'd really like to use this tool.

Answer (score 1):

[JsTestDriver IDEA plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4468) v1.3.7 built on JsTestDriver 1.3.3b works fine. IDEA 10.5 or higher is required. Also JsTestDriver plugin works with WebStorm/PhpStorm/PyCharm/RubyMine/AppCode.

Answer (score 0):

Using jsTestDriver 1.3.2, I get intermittent hangs running from the command line.  Restarting the server works around the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble, tends to be caused syntax errors in the code. It will give me the error once then it will just show 

`Total 0 tests (Passed: 0; Fails: 0; Errors: 0) (0.00 ms)
Tests failed: No tests executed.`

usually have to screw around with restarting servers/browsers to get it running again

Answer (score 0):

JsTestDriver-1.3.4-a( found in WebStorm jsTestDriver plugin Version 1.4.1, 2012 March).
Hangs after the mac sleeps (restarting the server works).